# Which is correct: "he don't" or "he doesn't"?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Which one is correct in a sentence?

> - He don't
> - He doesn't

I guess "he doesn't" should be correct because *he* is third person singular but I've seen some people using *do* with *he*. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`He doesn't` is correct, because it is the contraction of `He does not`.
`He don't` is incorrect, because it it the contraction of `He do not`.

Subject-Verb agreement requires that `he` goes with `does`.

`He don't`, however, is slang and certainly used in many places, but you would never see it in professional writing, because of Subject-Verb agreement.

Comment: You would never see it today in professional writing. In the 1880's educated people said "he don't" (they didn't write it much, because they didn't write contractions much. But you'll find it in the plays of W S Gilbert, given to upper-class characters). It is a matter of fashion, and the argument with which this answer begins is no more than a rationalisation.

Comment: I agree with you, @ColinFine , and IMO the rationalisation given for closing this question is no more than an [incorrect] answer. As your research and comment prove, neither "commonly-available references" nor those who rely solely on them for guidance hold all the answers.

Comment: Except for subjunctive and for some African dialects.

Comment: "is slang and certainly used in many places", where exactly?

Comment: It's common in [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English): "Verbs are uninflected for number and person: there is no -s ending in the present-tense third-person singular. ... AAVE *don't* for standard English *doesn't* comes from this"